# Javascript: How to find a key with a specific value, and then swap that key with that value

Tags: javascript, key, javascript-objects

I want to find all keys with the value "age," and swap them. But I don't want to swap every key

```
{
 const comiccharactersswap = Object.entries(comiccharacters).map(

    //But only if the value is "age"
    
    if (value == 'age')
    ([key, value]) => [value, key]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the condition inside the function, not around it.

```
const comiccharactersswap = Object.entries(comiccharacters).map(
    ([key, value]) => value == 'age' ? [value, key] : [key, value]
);
```

Comment: I probably should have been more specific with the question.

I am working with an array of objects, and this script ended up swapping the objects with their indexes. I need to get into each object in the array and exame the values and keys.

Would this need a map in a map? and if so, how?

Comment: This code is for processing just a single object. You can put this inside another `map()` to do it for every object in the array.